# Source and meaning of ἀεί ὁ ἄνθρωπος ἀριθμητίζει?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, translation-check

In the preface to the first edition of *Essays on the Theory of Numbers*, Dedekind writes:

> "In this sense which I wish to express by the word formed after a well-known saying ἀεί ὁ ἄνθρωπος ἀριθμητίζει, I hope that the following pages, as an attempt to establish the science of numbers upon a uniform foundation will find a generous welcome..." 
> <sub>Source: Hawking, *God Created the Integers*, reprinted courtesy of Dover Publications</sub>

I'm taking the Greek to mean something like **"Man always mathematizes"**, which in the context Dedekind is using it, relates to his idea that: *"Numbers are free creations of the human mind; they serve as a means of apprehending more easily and more sharply the difference of things."*

The phrase is quite similar to ἀεὶ ὁ θεὸς γεωμετρεῖ, attributed to Plato, translated as "God always geometrizes."

Three related questions, answers to any of which are welcome:

- Is my translation accurate?
- What's going on with ἀριθμητίζει?  I can't find that specific form, although the root and meaning seem clear.
- Is there a source for this phrase?  Does it come from the Classical period, or is it a later play on Plato's phrase?

Comment: I'm guessing the phrase is Dedekind's own. "Formed after a well-known saying" implies as much, though this English translation is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first inclination was that the verb means "count", not "mathematize", as the simple ἀριθμός means "number". This translation is supported by translator Robin Mackay in a pre-print draft translation of Alain Badiou's book, [Number and Numbers](http://www.mercaba.org/SANLUIS/Filosofia/autores/Contempor%C3%A1nea/Badiou/Number%20and%20numbers.pdf).

Thus, I would translate the phrase (as Badiou does): "Man always counts."

Mackay explains the history in a footnote.

> [aei o anthropos arithmetizei - "man always counts". Plutarch (Convivialium disputationum, liber
>   8,2) reports that : "Plato said God geometrizes continually". Kepler’s repetition of the statement in his
>   Mysterium Cosmographicum (either placatory or ironic, given the decidedly non-platonic nature of his
>   proposed coelestis machina) was followed by Gauss’s modification: o theos arithmetizei, god
>   arithmetizes, counts or calculates. Dedekind’s ‘copernican revolution’ consisted of transforming this
>   once again into: aei o anthropos arithmetizei - man is always counting; completing the transformation

So it started with Plato's phrase, ἀεὶ ὁ θεὸς γεωμετρεῖ. Then Gauss modified it to ἀεὶ ὁ θεὸς ἀριθμητίζει. Then Dedekind modified it to ἀεὶ ὁ ἄνθρωπος ἀριθμητίζει.

Indeed, the verb is hard to look up, and I will edit this post if I find an online entry.

Comment: "Man always counts" has a nice double-entendre in that "man is the measure of all things", although I might favor "man always calculates", because Dedekind comes after Laplace, who developed a fully formed theory of probability, thus a different, "game theoretic" double-entendre.  *(I'm a little surprised "[mathematize](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mathematize)" turns out to be actual word—I suspect I may have chosen it because of the zeta;)*  Wonderful answer.  Thank you so much!